# Integral of $f^2 (t)$

Tags: integration

$\int_0^1 f^2(t) $ should be somewhere between [0,1] for continous $f$ from $  [0,1] to [0,1]$. Is this true? I think it has to be. Since square of numbers less than 1 will be less than 1.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг: This is an answer.

Comment: @EricStucky Yes, but it is so small, that I thought I should put it as a comment.

Comment: I sympathize, but the site works most efficiently when answers are posted as answers.

Comment: @EricStucky Ok I get it. I shall post the above as an answer, and delete the above comment.

Answer (score 2):

Since $0 \leq f \leq 1$, $ 0 \leq f^2 \leq 1$, hence by domination theorem for integrals (or a near obvious fact):
$$
0 = \displaystyle\int_0^1 0 \; dt \leq \displaystyle\int_0^1 f^2(t)\; dt \leq \displaystyle\int_0^1 1\; dt = 1
$$
Hence, what you say is correct.